# format decimals

Tags: c#

I've found some example code which have this line

```
string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0};{1:f2};{2:f3};",item, someDecimalField, decimalAgain);
```

What are these `{1:f2};{2:f3}` and where I can found further info.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those are [`standard format strings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx).

`"F"` is the [`fixed point format specifier`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#FFormatString):

> The fixed-point ("F) format specifier converts a number to a string of
>   the form "-ddd.ddd…" where each "d" indicates a digit (0-9). The
>   string starts with a minus sign if the number is negative.
>
> The precision specifier indicates the desired number of decimal
>   places. If the precision specifier is omitted, the current
>   NumberFormatInfoNumberDecimalDigits property supplies the numeric
>   precision.

Answer (score 0):

Those are a simple object parameter like {0}, {1}, {2}. But the difference is that {1:f} has a more information that tells: output this parameter like a floating point.
For example {1:C} shows the output in the form of Currency.